How to mount specific fields in secretmanager using secretstore csi driver
Trying to mount only specific keys from the aws secretmanager as file to the pods using below.
Value of aws secret mytestsecret:
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}

SecretProviderClass spec
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: secretstore-test
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: "mytestsecret"
        objectType: "secretsmanager"
        jmesPath:
          - path: "key1"
          - objectAlias: "key1"

Deployment spec, removed other fields for brevity
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
        image: <>
        name: test
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mnt/secrets
          name: secrets-store-inline
      volumes:
      - csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: secretstore-test
        name: secrets-store-inline

with this spec, I'm getting two files mounted

one file named mytestsecret with full secret content including all fields

second file named key1, with only the value value2


Is there a way I can avoid the full secret file mount and only have file/s for the keys mentioned in jmespath?

Not sure on mounting as file but you can mount the specific key as env.
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: secretstore-test
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: "mytestsecret"
        objectType: "secretsmanager"
        jmesPath:
          - path: "key1"
          - objectAlias: "key1"
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: secretstore-test
    type: Opaque
    data:
      - objectName: key1
        key: key1


containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    env:
      - name: secret
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: secretstore-test
            key: key1


Works for Secrets, but I'm specifically looking for file mount.
